# Instantiating static nested classes without qualifying with enclosing class

Tags: java, static, nested

```
class OuterClass {
  static class StaticNestedClass {}
}
```

Above StaticNestedClass is instantiated by following syntax.

```
    OuterClass.StaticNestedClass nestedObject =
                      new OuterClass.StaticNestedClass();
```

This is easy to understand but my question is that the same nested class is instantiated by following code without using Outer class

```
  StaticNestedClass nestedObject =
                      new StaticNestedClass();
```

Kindly explain why did it not require OuterClass' qualification and still got compiled
Thanks

Comment: Where is it instantiated without the OuterClass qualification?

Comment: @Rob Watts Sir, I created a class OuterClass and its nested class in one java file and then in same package created a new class in which I instantiated the nested class of Outerclass. Thanks Sir...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This all depends on where the code is and (if applicable) what the `import` statements are. Any code in `OuterClass` automatically knows about the members of `OuterClass`, including any nested classes (static or not).

Code in other classes can also use an unqualified `StaticNestedClass` identifier if the class is imported:

```
import OuterClass.StaticNestedClass;

public class Elsewhere {
    StaticNestedClass nested = new StaticNestedClass();
    . . .
}
```

Without the `import`, code in class `Elsewhere` would need to use the qualified class name `OuterClass.StaticNestedClass`.

Answer (score 1):

Nested classes are divided into two categories: static and non-static. Nested classes that are declared static are simply called static nested classes. Non-static nested classes are called inner classes.

Static nested classes are accessed using the enclosing class name: